# Run legacy version of Firefox offline only side-by-side with Quantum?

Tags: firefox, windows-8.1, firefox-extensions

I used to use Firefox with the add-on Scrapbook, which is XUL-based, and broke with the introduction of Quantum.

I'd like to find and install a legacy version of Firefox to use offline-only, so I can look at and edit the pages I have already saved, and transfer the information to other programs.

What would be the most elegant way to go about this?  I am familiar with PortableApps, if that would make things easier to keep the legacy Firefox separate from my main installation.

My Scrapbook data is on my Windows computer running Windows 8.1 and Firefox 56.0 (64-bit).

Answer (score 0):

Yes portableapps.com package for [FireFox legacy  version 52](https://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox-portable-legacy-52)  would be way to go. [Download](https://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox-portable-legacy-52) and install in a new empty folder.  This would allow you to also install (either portable or regular install version)  and use the latest release of  FireFox Quantum on same machine without interference while still being able to use legacy extensions. But would recommend using legacy extensions and the legacy portable version of FireFox only to the extent absolutely necessary because of security concerns.